# Adding a list to a PreferencePage

Tags: preferences, eclipse-pde

**Update**:
So far I found class [ListEditor](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/preference/ListEditor.html) which provides the functionality I'm searching for except the 'edit' button and only for one column.

The ['Proxy bypass'](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/index.cgi/org.eclipse.ui.net/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/net/ProxyPreferencePage.java?revision=1.18&view=markup&sortdir=down) Page extends directly from PreferencePage. So there is no proper Base Class I could use.

--

The standard PDE way of adding Preference is to use field editors (for Boolean, String, Integer..) and subclass FieldEditorPreferencePage.

I'd like to integrate a list similar to the 'Network Connections' List in Preferences.

[Network Connections Preferences http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/4489/screencapturegw.png](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/4489/screencapturegw.png)

Is there a Standard List Class with Add/Edit/Remove Button I could use or is extending the PreferencePage and do all loading/saving manually the way to go?

the m2Eclipse Plugin also has a List [m2Eclipse http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/1972/screencapture1.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/1972/screencapture1.png)

it uses [TemplatePreferencePage](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/templates/TemplatePreferencePage.html), which has too much functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is there is no proper Base Class I could use.
However the [Proxy Bypass](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/index.cgi/org.eclipse.ui.net/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/net/ProxyPreferencePage.java?revision=1.18&view=markup&sortdir=down) Page is an example how to implement such a feature, it extends directly from [PreferencePage](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_preferencePages.html)

Answer (score 0):

I remember looking for something similar to edit a list of classpaths and did not find it.  JDT had something but it was too much for what I needed.  I think you have to do it on your own.  If you do something generic, you could file an enhancement request to platform UI at Eclipse and contribute it.  Doing it on my own was not too much work.